# Triangle of even numbers in java

Tags: java

How could I make the same triangle, but with even numbers, and with spaces?. How could I generate a number of even numbers without any limit, and be accommodated for the number of rows that the user enters (the user only enters the number of rows, but not a limit for the generation of even numbers or odd)

```
int num = 5;
int cont = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i ++) {
cont + = 2;
    for (int j = 0; j <num-i; j ++) {
    System.out.print ("");
}
    for (int k = i; k <cont; k ++) {
        System.out.print (k);
    }
    for (int l = i; l <cont-1; l ++) {
        System.out.print (l);
    }

System.out.println ("");
}
```

The run of this program is:

```
    1
   232
  34543
 4567654
567898765
```

what I want, but how could he do it?

```
     2
    4 6
  8 10 12
14 16 18 20
```

Comment: Have you tried yourself to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets you the result you want

```
    int rows = 500;

    //Calculating the largest number we will reach:
    int largest = 1;
    for(int i=1;i<=rows;i++){  

        largest=largest + i;    
    } 
    largest=largest*2;//since we only count even numbers


    int cur = 2; //current value to add to the triangle
    int rowsize = 0; //how many values to fit inside the row

    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i ++) {

        int cursize = 0; //ammount of values currently in the row

        //filling spaces on left side
        //The value is based on how many rows we want, more rows = need for more initial spacing
        String spaces = "";
        for(int j = 0 ; j < (rows + "").length() ; j++) {
            spaces += " ";
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= rows - i ; j++) {

            System.out.print(spaces);
        }

        while(cursize <= rowsize) {

            //For each number, we calculate how much spacing to place before it
            int len = (largest + "").length() - (cur + "").length();
            spaces = "";
            while(len != 0) {
                spaces += " ";
                len--;
            }

            System.out.print(" " + spaces + cur);
            cur += 2;
            cursize++;

        }

        System.out.println (""); //new line
        rowsize++;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: The code now manages the spacing and works up to 675 rows

Answer (score 0):

if I understand it correctly, it is easy but after number 5, number will go to each other, so if you want to avoid that, you must use 2 or 3 space for each number you print. The main triangle can created with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int row = in.nextInt();
    int allSpace = 2 * row - 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
        int allNumber = 2 * i - 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < (allSpace - allNumber) / 2; j++) {
            System.out.print("   ");
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= allNumber ; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%3d", j);
        }
        for (int j = allNumber - 1; j >= i ; j--) {
            System.out.printf("%3d", j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

But for even number you can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int row = in.nextInt();
    int allSpace = 2 * row - 1;
    int even = 2;
    for (int i = 1; i <= row; i++) {
        int allNumber = 2 * i - 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < (allSpace - allNumber) / 2; j++) {
            System.out.print("   ");
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= allNumber ; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%3d", even);
            even += 2;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Did I get it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky because the number of digits will affect the alignment slightly.

This will work:

```
    int num = 5;
    int cont = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        for(int k = 1; k <= num -i; k++) System.out.print(" ");
        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            cont += 2;
            System.out.print(cont + " ");
        }

    System.out.println ("");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int number=2;
for(int row=1;row<=4;row++) {
    for(int space=1;space<=(4-row);space++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for(int noOfValue=1;noOfValue<=row;noOfValue++) {
        System.out.print(number+" ");
        number=number+2;
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

- row --> It denotes the number of row it has.(it has 4 rows)
- space --> It denotes number of space in each row before beginning of first character.
- noOfValue --> It denotes how many value it has to print in each row.
- number --> It is the actual value which will be printed.